# Pass an array of interfaces into a function?

Tags: php, interface

In PHP since the interface benefits can used by passing as parameter mentioning the Interface name something like

```
public function foo (Abc $abc){}
```

where Abc is an interface.But how do I pass an array of these interfaces?

Please note this not class but interface and only way to get advantage of interface is passing as function with type hinting

Comment: In Hacklang (Facebooks extended PHP language) you can do `Vector<Abc>` to type hint a Vector (zero indexed list). Sadly PHP itself doesn't offer this afaik, at least not yet. You could hack your way around it though: [ensure you are working with "Array of Foo"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763744/type-hinting-specify-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: It's obviously not possible.

Comment: Why you can Not pass interface abc and need pas array?

Comment: @Naumov do you suggest passing each and every object individually? the what is the point of arrays?

Comment: that's not good idea to pass an array of interfaces. Doing so, you will loose "type hinting" benefits

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Can you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.6+ you could do something like this:

```
function foo(Abc ...$args) {

}

foo(...$arr);
```

`foo()` takes a variable amount of arguments of type `Abc`, and by calling `foo(...$arr)` you unpack `$arr` into a list of arguments. If `$arr` contains anything other than instances of `Abc` an error will be thrown.

This is a little 'hacky', but it's the only way to get type hinting for an array in PHP, without putting down some extra code.

Comment: the question is not about ability to accept different interface but rather passing an array of interfaces

Comment: I'm sorry, it looks like I misunderstood the question. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot check for two different interfaces at the same time using `type hinting` in PHP, but you can write a function for this which will check if the object belongs to multiple interfaces, eg -

```
function belongs_to_Interfaces($obj,array $interfaces)
{
    foreach($interfaces as $interface)
    {
         if(!is_a($obj,$interface))
         {
             return false;
         }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can then use it like this,

```
public function foo ($abc){
  if(!belongs_to_Interfaces($abc, ['interface1', 'interface2'])){
      //throw an error or return false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use PHP 5.6+ you can use variadic with decorator pattern:

```
<?php

interface Rule {
    public function isSatisfied();
}

final class ChainRule implements Rule {
    private $rules;

    public function __construct(Rule ...$rules) {
        $this->rules = $rules;
    }

    public function isSatisfied() {
        foreach($this->rules as $rule)
            $rule->isSatisfied();
    }
}
```