# Function return type hinting for an array of objects in PHP7

Tags: php, php-7

I am very happy with the new features in PHP 7. But I am confused on how to return an array of objects in PHP 7.

For example, we have a class `Item`, and we want to return an array of objects of this class from our function:

```
function getItems() : Item[] {
}
```

But it does not work this way.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I actually understand what you mean, but the answer unfortunately is that you can't do that. PHP7 lacks that kind of expressivity, so you can either declare your function to return "array" (a generic array) or you have to create a new class ItemArray which is an array of Item (but that meaning you will have to code it yourself).

There is currently no way to express "I want an array of Item" instances.

EDIT: As an added reference, here the ["array of" RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrayof) of what you wanted to do, it has been declined due to various reasons.

Comment: i thought moving to PHP 7 can help me to create a strict-typing code :/

Comment: I know, it is disappointing :( I added a reference to the RFC which talks exactly about the feature you asked about. It was declined.

Comment: @Johnny , I don't understand PHPs rfc voting method, there's no reasoning behind why they just deny stuff without a second glance, direct voting is not a good system for this

Comment: For now we can only use custom classes implementing ArrayAccess and Iterator interfaces and some custom validation for inputs.
Also RFC is from 2014 and it should be revisited. This will be one more step to typed arrays. Like in Java String[], int[].

Comment: That RFC is also very old and was proposed for php5.6. I think they should reconsider it now we are all heading towards strict typing it makes a lot more sense than it did back when it was initially proposed.

Answer (score 111):

You can type hint this way using [docblocks](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#5-the-phpdoc-format).

PHP editor (IDE) like [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) supports this very well and will properly resolve the class when iterating over such array.

```
/**
 * @return YourClass[]
 */
public function getObjects(): array
```

PHPStorm also supports nested arrays:

```
/**
 * @return YourClass[][]
 */
public function getObjects(): array
```

Newer versions of PHPStorm support phpstan/psalm format:

```
/**
 * @return array<int, YourObject>
 */
public function getObjects(): array
```

Or even generics:

```
/**
 * @template T of object
 * @param class-string<T> $className
 * @return array<array-key, T>
 */
public function getCollectionOf(string $className): array
```

Comment: yep, also suported by phpactor

Comment: Works also in NetBeans.

Comment: Just FYI, this doesn't work with VSCode + Intelliphense extension

Comment: I wouldn’t use anything else than PhpStorm.

Comment: @VladimirHidalgo I'm using VSCode with Intelephense and it works great

Comment: Although I upvoted you for "use phpdocs", this is not about >Generics<. As the main principe of generics is "Type is going to be specified later, use generic symbol insted of true type for now". In the desire stated here, type is known at the time of writing code.

Answer (score 13):

The current version of PHP doesn't support a built-in type hinting for *an array of objects*, as there is no such data type as "an array of objects". A class name can be interpreted as a type in certain contexts, as well as `array`, but not both at a time.

Actually you can implement such kind of strict type hinting by creating a class based on the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface, e.g.:

```
class Item
{
    protected $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}

class ItemsArray implements ArrayAccess
{
    private $container = [];

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        if (!$value instanceof Item) {
            throw new Exception('value must be an instance of Item');
        }

        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }
}


function getItems() : ItemsArray
{
    $items = new ItemsArray();
    $items[0] = new Item(0);
    $items[1] = new Item(2);
    return $items;
}

var_dump((array)getItems());
```

*Output*

```
array(2) {
  ["ItemsArrayitems"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["container"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Item)#2 (1) {
      ["value":protected]=>
      int(0)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Item)#3 (1) {
      ["value":protected]=>
      int(2)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a good one, but i prefer an automatic way, i hope they implement this feature in near future, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. One thing I noticed. Should it be                                                        
private $container = []; instead of private $items = []; ?

Comment: @kta, you are correct. I've edited the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment. But you can achieve your intended behavior with a custom array class

```php
function getItems() : ItemArray {
  $items = new ItemArray();
  $items[] = new Item();
  return $items;
}

class ItemArray extends \ArrayObject {
    public function offsetSet($key, $val) {
        if ($val instanceof Item) {
            return parent::offsetSet($key, $val);
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value must be an Item');
    }
}
```

Thanks to [bishop's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20763981/1280286)