# How can I define an array of object as a parameter in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to something like this:

```
function __construct (string $todo, array[Tag] $tags) {}
```

That `array[Tag]` caused me a problem with error along the line: `Unexpected '['`

The main idea is to have strict type checking for an array of an object with `Tag` class.

How can I achieve this? And is it necessary for PHP's best practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type hinting - specify an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763744/type-hinting-specify-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't. There is some hacky solution if you really need it though.