# How to create a `Typed` array in php?

Tags: php, strong-typing, type-declaration

I'd like to do something like that, creating a defined type array of `classA` inside `classB`, However, I can't find the syntax.

```
class classA{
}
```

```
class classB{
    private classA $someName:array;
}
```

Comment: There's no way for this. Only with phpdoc comments.

Comment: @u_mulder how does it relate to type-declaration?

Comment: What do you mean by "type array"? `classA $someName` denotes that that variable is of type `classA`, and not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are no typed arrays in php, but you may implement a wrapping class to an array, or a set of functions with variadic arguments. for instance:

```
class classB{
    private array $arr;
    public function __construct(classA ...$classAs){
       this->$arr = $classAs;
    }
}
```

you may read more about it here: https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/10040/approaches-to-creating-typed-arrays-in-php/

another approach could be to extend the array class, and make a typecheck with `instanceof` on each element as mentioned here: [Type hinting - specify an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763744/type-hinting-specify-an-array-of-objects)