# Is there a type hint for an array of objects of a specific class in PHP 8.3?

Tags: php, type-hinting, php-8.1, php-8.2

Is there a **type hint** in `PHP 8.3` which allows using `ExampleClass[]` for declaring it is an **array of objects** of the class `ExampleClass`?

---

In my specific case, `ExampleClass` is called `Task`

**What I want but does not work:**

```
private Task[] $tasks;
```

My PHPStorm IDE tells me that *Plural types are allowed only in doc types* 
 - speaking that only in `PHPDoc` using `Tasks[]` would be totally fine. But I want to use **plain PHP**.

The *error* is:
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "[", expecting variable`

---

**If I would only need one object `Task` and not an array of objects `Task[]` it would work with:**

```
private Task $task;
```

---

**This is my current, working workaround:**

```
private array $tasks;
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20763744/157957 https://stackoverflow.com/q/778564/157957

Comment: See also: [`arrayof RFC`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrayof)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The short answer is no.

My understanding is that enforcing such a thing has terrible performance problems. Some people want to go all the way and have full blown generics, others just want type-safe collections. Some people worry that implementing the latter *first* might hinder the development of the former in the future. So we’re at a standstill.

There’s the occasional discussion in the community such as this: https://externals.io/message/108175

**Edit**
Depending on how you interpret the question, [@Pierre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76120379/231316) could be considered more correct, since the OP said "type hint", although they showed a "type declaration".

There's a [good thread](https://externals.io/message/77252) from a while back arguing about the implications of what to call it, and that PHP's implementation is **not** a *hint* but a *declaration*. Some people argued that although calling it a "hint" is a misnomer, that shipped sailed and no matter what core changes, the community would still call it a hint. They did eventually update the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php), however, to use "type declaration".

Personally, I find myself still saying "type hint" for the explicit type declaration, but I try to catch and correct myself. I do this because I'm trying to change my mindset so that if I talk to a non-PHP person (usually a JavaScript person), they know that I'm not talking about IDE hints but true language features.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using PhpStorm, PHPStan or Psalm, types can be defined in PHPDocs and these tools will do the type checking, among many other things.

```php
/** @var Task[] $tasks */
private array $tasks;
```

Comment: That doesn't make the code itself type secure

Comment: The initial question was: Is there a type hint for an array of objects of a specific class in PHP 8.2?

Comment: Works with IntelliJ and other JetBrains products too

Answer (score 4):

While there is not a type hint available for such compound types, there is a workaround that enforces type. Create a subclass from ArrayObject and validate all values added to the ArrayObject. Then you can type hint your new subclass.

```
<?php

class Collection extends ArrayObject
{
    public function __construct(array $items = [])
    {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $this->validate($item)
        }
    }

    public function append($value): void
    {
        $this->validate($value);
        parent::append($value);
    }

    public function offsetSet($key, $value): void
    {
        $this->validate($value);
        parent::offsetSet($key, $value);
    }

    protected function validate($value): void
    {
        if (!$value instanceof Task) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                'Not an instance of Task'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can return objects with a type hint of `Collection` and it will behave exactly as an array of Task objects.

Comment: For those who are trying to implement this approach, please keep in mind that the constructor misses the parent constructor call after the loop - ```parent::__construct($items);```

Comment: Wouldn’t `!$value instanceof static` instead of `!$value instanceof Task` make the code more generic?

Answer (score 1):

With new PHP features you can ensure that your array is always of type `Task` using variadic:

```php
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var Task[] $tasks
     */
    private array $tasks = [];

    public function setTasks(Task ...$tasks) {
        $this->tasks = $tasks;
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->setTasks(...$tasksArray);
// or
$myClass->setTasks(new Task(), new Task(), new Task());
```

Since `setTasks` will always accept only `Task` as any parameter, there is no way to set anything else. We use this approach to bypass missing `arrayof` feature.

You can even incorporate magic methods to work with.

Comment: Nice one! Just want to mention that variadic functions were implemented using the `...` operator in PHP 5.6.  Then PHP 7 allowed you to declare types for variadic arguments.

Comment: Yes, it require parameter type hints. Also with union and intersection types it's very powerful