# How to define the return type of a function that returns an array of objects in php 8.2

Tags: php, laravel

For example, I develop an api and I have to type all my functions, I have a function that returns a list of movements, so how to define the return type of my function ? I tried to do this : `public function getAllMovements() : Movement[] {}` But it does'nt work, i work with laravel 10.

Comment: I think you saw a `TypeScript` mechanism and trying to implement it in `PHP`. As I know you can't. You can use predefined sets like, `array`, `resource`, `collection`, `bool` etc...

Answer (score -1):

I have defined a Movement Resource that return a movement collection

```php
class MovementResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

and in my function I have defined the resource as a return type and everything is working correctly

```php
public function getAllMouvements() : MovementResource {}
```

With this we are sure that the return type will be a collection of movements.

Comment: This is not what OP means. OP wants to indicate the type of the objects *inside* the array

Comment: I still think my code is relevant to his question, maybe i clarified with the comment inside of the function.

Comment: I do think this is what the OP means. **I have a function that returns a list of movements, so how to define the return type of my function ?** It is the return type of the function and not the type of the contents of the array. If it was to check what's inside the array and also typecheck that, it would not be possible IMO.

Comment: @Wimanicesir It would be if OP is able to create a class, e.g. `MovementCollection`, which inherits `ArrayAccess` as pointed out in the duped question

Comment: This is a correct answer, the answer simply is: either define `array` as return type (can't so `Array<Movement>` or have own type (class) and use that...

Comment: I finally found a solution, I created a laravel resource of the movements and I put it as return type like this

public function getAllMovements() : MovementResource {} ````

Now everything is OK

Answer (score -1):

If you want it only available in documentation, it's supported by phpdoc like so:

```
/**
 * @return Movement[]
 */
```

Else, I think you should create a strongly typed collection yourself, for example answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73738459/3090890

```
class MovementCollection extends ArrayObject
{
    public function __construct(array $items = [])
    {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $this->validate($item)
        }
    }
    ...
```

In API's its not uncommon to build typed collections like that.

Comment: *"In API's its not uncommon to build typed collections like that"* — That's probably because of the absence of generics.

Comment: It is not true that is common to have own definitions... Depends on the project, period