# How to declare an array of specific type in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to design a class which containes an array of another class objects

```php
<?php 

class X { };

class Y {
  private ?X[] items;
}
```

But this apparently doesn't work ..

I dont want to declare `items` as `array` because I need it to be in `X` type .

Comment: This is not currently possible directly in PHP. You need to either [create a dedicated subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20763981/231316) or just rely on type-hinting in PHP docblocks

Comment: No there's no such a thing in PHP. And you don't need it in this case, since your `items` is marked `private` and you can declare type in your setter method signature as `function addItem( \X $item ){...}`;

Comment: For further reference in case you are anyone else is interested, there was a specific [RFC dedicated to this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrayof), a [generic array RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generic-arrays), and a [full-blown generic RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics), all of which were declined or didn't make it into vote. There's links to the discussions if you want to learn about the reasons.